# Properly manipulating strings in TCL

Tags: tcl

Seems like a basic task, but I want to take a string that ends in something and replace the last 3 letters with something else. Here's my attempt:

```
set v "this is bob"
set index2 [string length $v]
set index1 [expr $index2 - 3]
set result [string replace $v index1 index2 dog]
puts $result; # I want it to now say "this is dog"
```

EDIT: Forgot to mention, the error message it gives me is:

```
bad index "index1": must be integer?[+-]integer? or end?[+-]integer?
    while executing
"string replace $v index1 index2 .hdr"
    invoked from within
"set result [string replace $v index1 index2 .hdr]"
    (file "string_manipulation.tcl" line 7)
```

Comment: Just for curiosity, why are you assuming that the last word will always be of 3 letters?

Comment: Because I'll be working with the file extension .am, and I wanna replace it with .hdr in order to save as a different output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to do it. Tcl recognizes tokens such as `end`, `end-1`, `end-2`, ... What you want is to replace from `end-2` to `end`:

```
set v "this is bob"
set result [string replace $v end-2 end "dog"]
# Result now is "this is dog"
```

## Update

If all you want to do is replacing the file extension, then use `file rootname` to remove the extension, then add your own:

```
set v filename.arm
set result [file rootname $v].hdr; # Replaces .arm with .hdr
```

This solution has the advantage of working with extensions of various lengths, not just 3.

Comment: +1. Alternatively, keep all but the last 3 chars: `set result "[string range $v 0 end-3]dog"`

Comment: I like this, much simpler

Answer (score 3):

Easy, you forgot you were in TCL right near the end.  Instead of passing in the *values* of **index1** and **index2**, you passed in the literal strings "index1" and "index2".  So just add the missing dollar signs:

```
set result [string replace $v $index1 $index2 dog]
```

Voila!  :-)

Comment: Well now don't I feel stupid. Those damn dollar signs always elude me